# Population Monte Carlo Algorithm using L2 Distance Measure/ Likelihood Distribution

Tags: optimization, monte-carlo, approximate-bayesian-computation, nonlinearity, inverse-problem

I am currently struggling with some concepts of the Population Monte Carlo Framework. Initially, I came across this  set of algorithms as I am currently trying to infer parameters from a 7D mechanistic model. Unfortunately, the model contains correction factors of the form

$g(x)= af(x)+b$

where $f(x)$ is the 7D model and $a,b$ are scaling and shift factors associated with the transformation of the measured current to the fundamental charge. The latter is what we want to describe based on fundamental parameters. The model has been tested against synthetic data and is valid. This is trying to move it to real measurement data.

Using standard nonlinear techniques to infer the parameters results in a strong dependence on starting point. Excessive sampling with 10M samples using Parallel Tempering gives reasonable answers but is extremely slow and requires a certain degree of manual adjustments of the covariance matrix to achieve adequate sampling rates across various datasets.

Being a lazy student, I looked for something automatic before resigning to manual tuning. Here I came across the Approximate Bayes set of algorithms. I used the previous described approach by [Mark A. Beaumont(2009)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0805.2256).

This worked great. It was able without much tuning to work out the parameters  across various datasets, and only a little slower than the PT approach. Now though I discussed the results with one of the post docs supervising me. He wanted me to test out if it also worked with an L2 Distance Metric or a assumed Gaussian Likelihood instead of L1.

This no longer is Approximate Bayesian computation and is more like the original Population Monte Carlo approach. In the ABC scheme, there is the acceptance of a move based on the distance which should be less than $\epsilon_t$. I can not find a similar step in the original paper by [Cappe 2004](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~xian/0215ihp2.ps.gz). Is there an "acceptance criterion"?

Thank you very much for your answers/ lit references in advance. A bit at a loss here.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand most of the question. From the model correction to the mention of $L¹$ versus $L²$ to the connection with ABC... Our 2004 paper (and subsequent ones) are about importance sampling, hence unconnected with ABC.

Comment: It might be a misunderstanding on my part. ABC allows for evaluation of the posterior for complex likelihood functions. In our case an analytical likelihood exists, but discontinuous due to boundary conditions. As the ABC PMC algorithm worked far better than any other inference, the idea was to try and evaluate the real posterior using PMC. Comparing your 2004 paper to Beaumont, the difference seemed the acceptance step and likelihood function.Acceptance eludes me as the weights using a uniform prior do not seem to work with just the ratio of $[\pi /q]$. Am I missing monte carlo like step?

Comment: ABC does not use the likelihood but a simulated estimator that is one or zero depending on the proximity of the simulated data to the true data. This makes for a _big_ difference with regular Monte Carlo methods.

Comment: Yes. An estimator for how closely the data is simulated by a set of parameters. In the ABC approach thus the move is accepted based on some adaptive threshold /epsilon_t. Now if I where to convert the estimator to a likelihood distribution, the algorithm would be a pure PMC, targeting the true posterior. What  happens to the acceptance step? Specifically, in step b) of the 2004 paper is the ratiou /rho = (/pi/q) used to accept/reject moves based on some probability or is the convergence purely enforced by the weigths used

Comment: If so, do the weights always converge in the case of a uniform prior?  Thank you for your time! Sorry to be confounding things most probably.

Comment: I fear you need more MCMC and probability background than I can provide through comments.

Comment: That's why I asked the question as I feared I was missing something. The above might not be clearly formulated as It should have been. Basically, I was refering to the algorithmic steps and that in the Beaumont paper in addition to proposing from the weighted normalised prior a threshold limit is introduced when accepting new proposed particles. This threshold is not present in the PMC targeting the true marginal posterior as far as I can tell.  I would be grateful for any literature references or books you could recommend. Thanks in advance!